# How to find the most specific file with client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-404, lookup

Using only client side JavaScript I need to find the most specific data file for a given web page, depending on its pathname.

Let's say I'm on `example.com/foo/bar`, and for the /foor/bar pathname the following data files can possibly exist:

- /data.js
- /foo/data.js
- /foo/bar/data.js

It is entirely possible that the most specific `/foo/bar/data.js` file will not exist. It is also possible that only the most generic `/data.js` file is available for the current path.

This lookup would have to be done once per each page view.

It would be too wasteful, therefore impossible to have all the data files in a single, aggregated resource because of the huge number of pathnames and data in the files.

My first idea for a solution is to attempt to load all the possible data files with AJAX, discard those that return a 404 error, then find the most specific one among the result.

This would work I think, but I don't like the idea of having to "bomb" the server and generate a few (0–4) 404 errors for a given page.

Can you recommend a better approach?

Comment: Just an idea here, but wouldn't it be better if you actually kept track of where you put your files?

Comment: Unfortunately no, our client side script does not have any information on the existence of the possible data files. It is also not possible to generate a separate, aggregated data file for each page as the page creator technology is a black box in this situation and we have no control over it. (Actually, there are many separate page generators, so we're talking about several such black boxes.)

Comment: ^^ That's much better than my idea, and it's what I would do, just light that shit up.

Comment: Is setting up a proxy server an option? Like `my-proxy.net/get/foo/bar/data.js` instead of `your-server.com/foo/bar/data.js`? If yes, you can cache trial-and-error requests on the proxy.

Comment: @georg, letting the proxy hide the errors would enhance the solution but would not eliminate the 404 errors. I would still feel dirty. :)